# TableView reloads and adds(repeats) the original data every time user signs

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, firebase

I've ran into an issue with my tableview when signing in using Firebase in my iOS application. The table loads contents from a son feed. When I first sign in the table loads fine but if I sign out and sign in again the table reloads all of the data adding the original data to the contents of the table. I tried checking whether the table was empty before reloading but had no effect.

Closing the application has no issues. The problem only happens if the user signs out of the application using the signet button in the account view controller and signs back in. I would like to figure out what makes the table add the same data to it or maybe empty the table when the user signs out but haven't able to figure out either one.

This is the code to load the function. I had placed this code in viewWillAppear or viewDidLoad but makes no difference.

```
    if tableView.visibleCells.isEmpty {
        loadTableData()
    } else {
        //do something
    }
```

This is my load data function

```
func loadTableData() {
    let url = "https://JSONurl.json"
    let headers: HTTPHeaders = [
        "X-API-Key": api.key,
        "Accept": "application/json"
    ]

    Alamofire.request(url, headers: headers).validate().responseJSON { response in
        switch response.result {
        case .success:
            if let value = response.result.value {
                let json = JSON(value)
                self.parseJSON(json: json)
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        case .failure(let error):
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "title", message: "message", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
            let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "title", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil)
            alert.addAction(okAction)
            self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
            print(error)
        }
    }
}
```

In my signing view controller I authenticate the user with the following code

```
func authenticateUser() {
    guard let userEmailAddress = userEmailAddressTextField.text, !userEmailAddress.isEmpty else {
        // alert error message
        return
    }

    guard let userPassword = userPasswordTextField.text, !userPassword.isEmpty else {
        // alert error message
        return
    }

    Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: userEmailAddress, password: userPassword) {
        (user, error) in
        if let error = error {
            self.commonFunctions.showAlertMessage(viewController: self, alertTitle: AppConstants.AlertMessages.firebaseAuthErrorTitle, messageToDisplay: error.localizedDescription)
            return
        }
        if user != nil {
            let mainPage = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "viewControllerWithTable") as! UITabBarController
            self.present(mainPage, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
}
```

This is my code in the AppDelegate inside the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions function. This so that the user does not have to login again if closing the application.

```
    if Auth.auth().currentUser != nil && Auth.auth().currentUser!.isEmailVerified {
        let mainStoryBoard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name:"Main", bundle:nil)
        let nextView: UITabBarController = mainStoryBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "viewControllerWithTable") as! UITabBarController
        self.window?.rootViewController = nextView
    }
```

My parseJSON is as follows:

```
func parseJSON(json: JSON) {
    for item in json["results"][0]["members"].arrayValue {
        item.id = (item["id"].stringValue)
        // omitted extra data
        let eachItem = ItemInit(id: item.id!)
        items.group.append(eachItem)
    }
    sortData()
    utils.hideActivityIndicator()
}
```

My sign out is inside an IBAction for when the user taps the button. I'm sending the user back to the WelcomeViewController where the user can choose how to sign in again (email, social media).

```
    do {

        try Auth.auth().signOut()
        let nextView  = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "WelcomeViewController") as! WelcomeViewController
        let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate
        appDelegate?.window??.rootViewController = nextView

    } catch{
        // alert user
    }
```

Comment: remove this **tableView.visibleCells.isEmpty** as it's useless , you need to only clear the dataSource  array before adding the data

Comment: Can you show how you implemented this function `parseJSON(json: json)`. And also, how are you handling logout

Comment: I added the parseJSON and signout above. Thanks

Comment: I've tried clearing the dataSource array before adding the data but that doesn't work.

Comment: Where do you clean your dataSource? Can you try clearing it in a ViewWillAppear function? Also can you show your tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int)  function?

Comment: override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if searchController.isActive && (searchController.searchBar.text!.isEmpty == false || !filteredItems.isEmpty) {
            return filteredItems.count
        } else {
            if (nameStateSegmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 0) {
                return sectionsSortedByName[section].length
            } else {
                return sectionsSortedByCategory[section].length
            }
        }
    }

Comment: I've tried clearing data in viewwillappear and viewdidload but no changes.

Answer (score 0):

Try to clean your dataSource before add anything.

```
func parseJSON(json: JSON) {
    items.group.removeAll()
    for item in json["results"][0]["members"].arrayValue {
        item.id = (item["id"].stringValue)
        // omitted extra data
        let eachItem = ItemInit(id: item.id!)
        items.group.append(eachItem)
    }
    sortData()
    utils.hideActivityIndicator()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I don't know why the other options named above didn't work but this is what I eneded up doing. I used NotificationCenter
I added this below the sign out view controller

```
NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name("clearTable"), object: nil)
```

And on the view controller with the table I added this inside the ViewDidLoad:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(clearTable), name: Notification.Name("clearTable"), object: nil)
```

and added the following function:

```
@objc func clearTable() {
    items.group.removeAll()
}
```

I still don't understand why placing items.group.removeAll() before loading the table wouldn't work. Looks like the same thing almost.